# as2 loadmovie problem

Tags: flash

When I am use this mc is loaded.

```
loadMovie("contact/contact.swf",1);
```

But When I use this not load mc.

```
example = "contact/contact.swf";
loadMovie(example,1);
```

How can I do this? Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
var example:String = "contact/contact.swf"; 
loadMovie(example,1);
```

Comment: thanks BTellez. I try this but not work. I am use as2. This code failed

Comment: my code; menu_item_group["menu_item"+i].onRelease = function() 
 {
  example = "contact/contact.swf";
  loadMovie(example,1);
 }                                                        When I use your code, not give errors. But not show swf

Comment: How about using the alternative function:    loadMovieNum(example,1); or use: someNewEmptyMovieClip.loadMovie(example);